# layout-small is not using images from drawable-ldpi

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a layout for small devices separately in `layout-small` and I have added the images used in that layout into `drawable-ldpi` , but I dont know why `layout-small` is not using small images from `drawable-ldpi` even the names of images are same.

Note:

I have `layout A` and inside that i have included `layout B` and both are included in 
`layout-small` only.

I have also run a test to check under which category my device falls and as a result 
its showing

`small sized screen` and density is `120` i.e. LOW DENSITY

**Update**

I have `layout` , `layout-small` and `layout-port` folder and here `layout-port` is using small images rather then `layout-small` , how would i diffrenciate between them ?

Comment: I take back my (now deleted) comment earlier. I've just checked on the specs for the Wildfire and done the calculations and, as Sky Kelsey states above, it seems it should definitely be classed as small/ldpi. I'm not sure why it's not using the right images. Very odd.

Comment: @Squonk please see my upate

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to target based on screen SIZE, but you are adding images based on screen DENSITY. While the density of your device may in fact be LDPI, it may not in fact by SMALL.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

I suggest you check the screen dimensions to see if perhaps your screen is in fact of MEDIUM size.

Edit: The HTC Wildfire has a screen of 3.2 inches @ 240 x 320, which gives it a DPI of 125. This definitely SHOULD place if in both the SMALL and LDPI category, but maybe it was miscategorized?

Comment: ya dimension is `240x320` only

Comment: I have `layout-port` and `layout-small` i dont know why but `layout-port` is using small images , how can i differentiate between two